# Laggy SSH sessions on local network

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, ssh

I have two machines:

- Windows 7 connected by ethernet to a router
- NixOS laptop, connected wirelessly to same router

My issue is that sshing from Windows to NixOS is extremely laggy. If I ping NixOS from Windows, I get times of about 100ms - 200ms.
If I do the reverse- ping Windows from NixOS- I get times < 10ms.

The NixOS install is recent. Prior to this, I had Arch Linux, which did not suffer the same problem. I don't recall any other changes.

Additionally, I can ssh to a remote server not on the LAN. SSHing from either Windows or NixOS to the remote server has no issues whatsoever with lag.

I have tried the following:

- setting this option in sshd's config: `UseDNS no`
- setting my nameserver to `8.8.8.8`

However, these haven't helped (seems to be a lower-level issue than sshd)

My question: what do I need to do to stop SSH lagging?

Comment: Can you connect the laptop to a wired network? Just to exclude some factors...

Comment: Unfortunately I only have one ethernet cable :(. Pinging NixOS from another windows laptop on the wireless network shows similarly slow replies (~ 100-200ms)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=182992), which suggests running the following command as root:

```
iw wlp2s0 set power_save off
```

I ran this on my NixOS machine. This turns off power saving for the wifi network device `wlp2s0`. If you have a differently-named device (like `wlan0`), you need to use that name instead.

SSH is now much more responsive, and ping times are also back down to < 5ms.

Comment: And is it faster now?

Comment: er, yes. embarassed to have neglected that. I will edit the answer.

Comment: It's magic. It really works.

Comment: Can confirm this solved my issue. I went from 30ms to 500ms ping, to 2ms to 6ms ping. Be warned that this setting will reset on reboot, but you can make it permanent by following this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315400/438536

Answer (score 1):

Since this is also a Nix related question, I'd put my two cents in as I strumbled into this problem as well.

I'm using networkmanager so the wifi powersave can be disabled by setting
the following config:

```
networkmanager.wifi.powersave = false;
```

For `wpa_supplicant` I think it should be the following configuration, but I have not tested it by myself:

```
networking.wireless.extraConfig = ''
  power_save=0
'';
```